# How to use Timetable.js in ionic2 typescript

Tags: javascript, ionic2

Is it possible to use timetable.js in ionic2 project?

http://timetablejs.org/

I tried to create timetable.d.ts as belows.

```
declare class Timetable {
  constructor();
  scope: string;
  locations: Array<string>;
  events: Array<any>;
  setScope(start: number, end: number);
  addLocations(locations: Array<string>);
  addEvent(artistCode: string, stageCode: string, startDate: Date, endDate: Date);
  Renderer(tt: any);
}
```

And I tried these three different code.

```
var renderer = Timetable.Renderer(timetable);
```

=> It works correctly but TypeScript compile error occurs: Property 'Renderer' does not exist on type 'typeof Timetable'

```
var renderer = timetable.Renderer(timetable);
```

=> compile is ok but it doesn't display anything.

```
var renderer = new timetable.Renderer(timetable);
```

=> compile error: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword. and it doesn't display anything.

Should I just keep 1st code?

Please give me any information, link or suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling Renderer statically, which won't be a problem for javascript at runtime, that's why it still works. You can either declare it like `static Renderer(tt: any);` or call it as a method of a `Timetable` object as you declared. If timetable is an object that you have already created, then you can try `var renderer = new timetable.Renderer(timetable)` which is a bit weird but might work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I needed to remove 'new' keyword after added 'static' keyword.

Comment: Actually after I added 'static' keyword, error stopped but it became data did not show up. I found that the reason of plain text was wrong css file name. Now it's working correctly but still I get compile error.. should I just ignore this error?

Comment: you are still trying to call Renderer statically, which doesn't matter for javascript but does for typescript, that's why it still works.See my edit to the answer for an alternative

Comment: thanks, I tried `var renderer = new timetable.Renderer(timetable)` and other syntax error occured: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword. Then I removed 'new' but both doesn't work. Am I doing wrong way? See my edit.