# How to use Timetable.js in Angular typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement this nice javascript plugin into an Angular6 project :
[Timetable.js](http://timetablejs.org/) / [on Github](https://github.com/Grible/timetable.js)

Looking for a way to do it I've come accross this :
[How to use Timetable.js in ionic2 typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252369/how-to-use-timetable-js-in-ionic2-typescript). The post is two years old and it seems that the problem hasn't been solved.
Based on the code [tmnrkb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1922885/tmnrkb) posted I've written that code in my app.component, after declaring the js script file in the angular.json file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare class Timetable {
  constructor();
  scope: string;
  locations: Array<string>;
  events: Array<any>;
  Renderer(tt: any): any;
  setScope(start: number, end: number);
  addLocations(locations: Array<string>);
  addEvent(artistCode: string, stageCode: string, startDate: Date, endDate: Date);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  timetable = new Timetable();

  constructor() {
    this.addTimeTable();
  }

  addTimeTable() {
    this.timetable.setScope(9, 3);

    this.timetable.addLocations(['London', 'Paris', 'Los Angeles']);

    this.timetable.addEvent('Sightseeing', 'London', new Date(2018, 8, 25, 9), new Date(2018, 8, 26, 12));

    this.timetable.addEvent('Zumba', 'Paris', new Date(2018, 8, 27, 9), new Date(2018, 8, 29, 12));

    this.timetable.addEvent('Cocktails', 'Los Angeles', new Date(2018, 8, 22, 9), new Date(2018, 8, 23, 12));

    const renderer = this.timetable.Renderer(this.timetable);
    // const renderer = new Timetable.Renderer(this.timetable);
    renderer.draw('.timetable');
  }



}
```

When I run ng serve it compiles the code but in the console I've got this error:

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: this.timetable.Renderer is not a function
    at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.addTimeTable (app.component.ts:39)
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:25)
```

So I wonder why it says that Renderer is not a function.

Comment: Ok, it's getting there... I've converted the plugin js file to Typescript classes & interface. Now it's kind of working ok. I've got no errors but I've encountered few issues when displaying the html: it doesn't match the events durations and the header doesn't scroll...Working on it. If anyone is interested I'll push it on my Github when I solve that.

Answer (score 1):

So based on [Timetable.js](http://timetablejs.org/), ([the plugin's Github](https://github.com/Grible/timetable.js)) I managed to make it work in Angular by converting it to Typescript.
Here's the result on my [Github](https://github.com/zulihan/ng-timetable), in case someone is interested.
Thanks to [stevenaanen](https://github.com/Grible/timetable.js/commits?author=stevenaanen) 'cause his plugin is exactly what I needed.